# Parametric equation of a closed curve

Tags: parametric, parametrization

What do you call such a figure below and how to parametrize such kind of curve?

[image: a dumb bell like curve]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_oval

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a variant of the dumbbell curve (see e.g. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DumbbellCurve.html)
This one could be parametrized for the upper part by
$$x(t)=t,\ y(t)=(t^2 + 0.5)\sqrt{1 - t^2}$$
and the lower part by
$$x(t)=t,\ y(t)=-(t^2 + 0.5)\sqrt{1 - t^2}$$
for $t\in[-1,1]$.
Of course you can change the $0.5$ to a different positiv value to obtain different shapes.